# How can I create a function that converts a string directly into binary?

Tags: python

Hi i need a def that does the same work than this :

```
st = "c.cl"
print("".join(format(ord(x), 'b')for x in st) )
```

But I can't use list comprehension and bitwise xor. i've been thinking and i don't know

Comment: you can always use a loop to replace a list comprehension

Comment: why can't you use list comprehensions?

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap it in a function.

```
def get_bits(s):
    return "".join(map(lambda x: format(ord(x), 'b'), s))
```

Using it:

```
>>> get_bits("c.cl")
'110001110111011000111101100'
```

Comment: This still uses a list comprehension, which was disallowed as per the OP's requirements. (Makes no sense to have such a requirement, but there you have it.)

Comment: Ditto was triplee said.

Comment: Okay, I will remove the use of the actual list-comprehension, implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by gefei, you can use a loop to replace a list comprehension.

```
def convert(some_string):
    _return = ""
    for char in some_string:
        _return += format(ord(char), 'b')

    return _return

print convert("cheese")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this then?

```
def binary (str):
    b = []
    for x in str:
        b.append(format(ord(x), 'b')
    return "".join(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

```
def convert(s):
    r = ""
    for c in s:
        r += "{0:b}".format(ord(c))

    return r
```

Comment: This was really nice and short :)

Answer (score 0):

The comprehension:

`[format(ord(x), 'b') for x in st]`

can be rewritten as:

`map(lambda x: format(ord(x), 'b'), st)`